# Interpreting regression results with one log transformed independent variable

Tags: regression, interpretation, logarithm

I have a following OLS regression model

```
log(y) = a + b*x_1 + c*x_2 + d*log(x_3) + error
```

I am now wondering what is the interpretation of the coefficient `d`- is it that one unit change in `log(x_3)` causes `d` units change to the `log(y)`? Are there any extra consequences of one independent variable being log transformed that I should be aware of?

Many thanks!

Comment: Hi: For every 1 percent change in x_3, there is a d percent change in y. It seems a little odd to me transform one of the independent variables but not the others. When I say, "odd:, I mean that it's a little strange that one would work better using the log scale and the others wouldn't need it ?  But that would depend on the meanings of the variables. I'm not sure about other consequences but I don't know of any.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the variable x_1 to x_1 + 1 and keep all the other variables the same, then you have odd_post/odd_pre = exp(beta1), since you have log(y)  = beta_i*x_i => y = exp(beta_i*x_i) and all the other terms cancel.